# Preprocess from caret package

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

I was given 5000 SIFT features for each grey-scale image of either a poodle dog or fried chicken, and asked to build a model for classification.

I ran preProcess function on the matrix of sift features:

```
mat1=preProcess(mat, method=c("pca", "zv"))
```

What I get is a class "preprocessed", and I do not know how to use this object `mat1` in the following function call:

```
model_gbm <- train(ensembleData[,predictors], ensembleData[,labelName], method='gbm',  trControl=myControl)
```

ensembleData[, predictors] used to contain the feature part of the sift features, and ensembleData[, labelName] contained the actual class (0 or 1) of the data.

I have thought about using the `preProcess` function inside of the `train` function, but I want to be able to use the same preprocessed data elsewhere in other models.

Thanks!

Comment: *but I want to be able to use the same preprocessed data elsewhere in other models.* No. The idea of using a [dog](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2305310/Man-gets-shock-toy-poodles-turn-GIANT-RODENTS-steroids.html)/chicken classifier on anything else is a [bad idea](http://www.marietta.com/images/the-big-chicken.jpg).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry, I meant to say, I want to try out different classifier on the same data and possibly use ensemble learning. But LOL at the links.

Comment: Oh, [SparkR](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html) then. Also, that's a huge undertaking. And [good luck](http://img2.timeinc.net/people/i/2007/specials/halloween/dogs/dog_chicken3.jpg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [caret documentation](https://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#pp)

> The function preProcess estimates the required parameters for each operation and predict.preProcess is used to apply them to specific data sets

So you need to apply the estimated parameters to your data like so:

```
mat1=preProcess(mat, method=c("pca", "zv"))
transformed = predict(mat1, mat)
model_gbm <- train(data=transformed, method='gbm',  trControl=myControl)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However, I have another question. I used to split the data in mat into two parts for cross-validation purposes. Now, mat1 becomes a Large preProcess, I have no idea how to split the data and use the splitted data into the following function: `p_gbm = predict(object=model_gbm, testingData[,predictors])` , where `testingData[, predictors])` contains the portion of the data not in training set.

Comment: Why not split your data first?  So that this is not an issue.